# Why python package is installed with dash in its name?

Tags: python, setup.py

I have the following setup.py file:

```
setup(
     name='reports_parsers',
     version='0.1',
     ...
)
```

When I run command `python setup.py install`, the package is installed with the name `reports-parsers==0.1`, which I can not import due to SyntaxError.

How can I make installation with right name?

Comment: Remove the `_` from the name of the package?

Comment: @bastelflp isn't it possible to use underscore in a package name?

Comment: Referring to [PEP0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) it should be possible...

Comment: Did you find out how to preserve the underscore?

Comment: @vinyll as far as I remember I removed `_`

Comment: Is there an update to this question? I experience the same issue with a local `pip install -e` containing underscores. `pip freeze` shows that the module is installed with minuses ("-") as word separators instead of the original underscores ("_").